# IIS redirect Multiple domains allow one access to folder - deny access to other

Tags: redirect, iis

How can I create a redirect rule to that will allow access to one folder from Domain2.com and deny/redirect to root if access from Domain1.com

Basically we want the admin console to not be access from Domain1 and set it up on Domain2.

I tried to use negagte in the redirect rules but that did not for me.

```
    <!-- Redirect Domain1 Admin to Homepage -->
    <rule name="RedirectAdmintoHomepage">
      <match url="https://www.domain1.com/admin" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain1.com/" />
    </rule>
    <!-- End Redirect Domain1 Admin to Homepage -->

         <rule name="Redirect .aspx to non aspx" stopProcessing="true">
                      <match url="(.*).aspx" />
                      <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="admin" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="userlogin" negate="true" />
                      </conditions>
                      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
            </rule> 

                        <rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
<!-- Exclude Domain2 redirection -->
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="https://console.domain2.com" negate="true" />  
<!-- Exclude Domain2 redirection -->
</conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain1.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

In short basically

DisAllow https://www.domain1.com/admin

Allow https://console.domain1.com/admin (*)

Comment: First fix the typical mistakes and update your question, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: @user204245  Is your issue solved?
If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.
If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members.
If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it.
We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

you could use below url rewrite rule to disallow https://www.domain1.com/ to access the admin folder and allow https://console.domain1.com/

```
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule14" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.domain1.com" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="admin/(.*)" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="console.domain1.com" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain1.com/" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
```

Note: there is some issue in you **Force WWW and SSL** rule. you need to correct that rule first.